# catch (QuotaExceededException ex) and get something useful?

Tags: c#, wcf

The only message it pushes back to me is:

```
{"The size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota."}
System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException
```

Do I need more room in my transport?  Like increase either the maxBufferPoolSize or maxReceiveMessageSize ?

```
<httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="500000"
  maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" allowCookies="false" 
  authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" 
  maxBufferSize="500000" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
  realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
  useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
```

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah - I see you've already upped the values of those

<strike>There's also `maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxReceiveMessageSize` which ought to be increased,</strike> 
and then there's the whole plethora of the `<ReaderQuotas>` which also sometimes come into play (as a subnode of the `<httpBinding>`).

```
<wsHttpBinding .......>
    <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="32"
            maxStringContentLength="8192"
            maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096"
            maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Those are the default values - try increasing the maxArrayLength and maxStringContentLength first.

Also, remember to set those new values both on the client and the server side!

Marc